# PyCryptoScraper to scrape currency rates

Tags: python, web-scraping, cryptocurrency, python-requests

I created a PyCryptoScraper script to scrape crypto-currencies from [Coingecko](https://www.coingecko.com/de). Now I want to know if you could give me some hints or improvements for my script, which works fine.

The whole code also can be downloaded on [GitHub](https://github.com/patrick0585/PyCryptoScraper).

**Dependencies**

[marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

> `marshmallow` is an ORM/ODM/framework-agnostic library for converting
>   complex datatypes, such as objects, to and from native Python
>   datatypes.
>
> `marshmallow` can be installed with pip:
>
> ```
> pip install -U marshmallow --pre
> ```

**Usage**

To run PyCryptScraper you need to instantiate the class `CryptoScraper`:

```
cryptoscraper = CryptoScraper(currencies_to_scrape=[dict(name='bitcoin', tags=['usd', 'eur'])])
```

or you can execute the python script Scraper.py with certain parameters:

```
python Scrape.py -c "[{'name':'bitcoin','tags':['usd','eur']}]"
```

My code looks like so:

**Scraper.py**

```
# coding: utf-8
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from scraper.CryptoScraper import CryptoScraper
from schema.DataSchema import DataSchema
import optparse
import sys
import ast
import json

def scrape():
    crypto_scraper = CryptoScraper(currencies_to_scrape=valid_currencies)

    results = crypto_scraper.scrape()

    print json.dumps(results)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = optparse.OptionParser("usage: %prog [options] arg1")
    parser.add_option("-c", "--currencies", dest="currencies", type = "str", help = "specify currencies to scrape")
    parser.add_option("-o", "--output", dest="output", type="str", default="json", help="specify output format")

    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

    if len(args) != 0:
        parser.error("incorrect number of arguments")

    currencies_to_scrape = ast.literal_eval(options.currencies)
    output = options.output

    # validate currency data
    valid_currencies, errors = DataSchema(many=True).load(currencies_to_scrape)

    if errors:
        print 'error validating data'
        print "data-format:  [{'name':'bitcoin','tags':['usd','eur']}]"
        sys.exit(0)

    # scraping the currencies
    scrape()
```

**scraper/Base.py**

```
# coding: utf-8

from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod


class CryptScraperBase(object):
    """
        Base class for the crypto-scraper
    """
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def _extract(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ extracting data"""

    @abstractmethod
    def _transform(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ transform data"""
```

**scraper/CryptoScraper.py**

```
# coding: utf-8

from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from scraper.Base import CryptScraperBase
from schema.DataSchema import DataSchema

from lxml import html
import re
import time
import requests


class CryptoScraper(CryptScraperBase):

    def __init__(self, currencies_to_scrape):
        """
            Initializes the crypto-scraper
        :param currencies_to_scrape: Currencies to scrape
                                    format:  [{ name => "bitcoin", tags => ["usd", "eur"] }, ...]
        :type currencies_to_scrape: list
        """
        self.base_url = 'https://www.coingecko.com/de/kurs_chart/'

        valid_currencies, errors = DataSchema(many=True).load(currencies_to_scrape)
        if not errors:
            self.currencies_to_scrape = valid_currencies
        else:
            # TODO: Throw in error if the currencies are not valid
            pass

    def _extract(self, name, tag, *args, **kwargs):
        """
            Extract data from the given url
        :param name: CryptCurrency name
        :type name: str
        :param tag: Tag for the CryptCurrency
        :type tag: str
        :param args:
        :param kwargs:
        :return:
        """
        status_code, content = self.get_page_content(name, tag)
        if status_code == 200:
            return content
        else:
            raise ('page is not available')

    def _transform(self, page_content, exchange_rate, *args, **kwargs):
        """
            Transforms the extraced data into an given format
        :param page_content: extraced page content in html
        :type page_content: str
        :param args:
        :param kwargs:
        :return: Transformed CryptCurrency Details
        """
        return self._get_currency_details(page_content, exchange_rate)

    def scrape(self):
        """
            Scrape Crypt-Currencies from the given page
        :return: Scraped Crypt-Currencies
        """
        results = []

        for currency in self.currencies_to_scrape:
            name = currency.get('name')
            tags = currency.get('tags')

            for tag in tags:
                page_content = self._extract(name=name, tag=tag)
                crypt_currency = self._transform(page_content=page_content, exchange_rate=tag)
                results.append(crypt_currency)

        return results

    def get_page_content(self, name, tag):
        """
            Returns content from the page crypto-currencies are listed
        :param name: Crypto-Currency name
        :type name: str
        :param tag: The Tag for the crypto-currency (usd, eur, ..)
        :type tag: str
        :return: The page content and statuscode
        """
        response = requests.get(self.base_url+name+'/'+tag)
        return response.status_code, response.content

    def clean_currency_amount(self, data):
        m = re.search(r'^\s+(.*\d+)\s+.*', data)
        if m:
            return m.group(1)

    def _get_currency_details(self, page_content, exchange_rate):
        """
            Get all details for an crypt-currency
        :param page_content: The html page content with crypt-currency information
        :type page_content: str
        :return: extracted details for an given crypt-currency
        """
        tree = html.fromstring(page_content)

        # Options for xpath
        opts = {
            'currency': '1',
            'code': '2',
            'exchange_rate': '3',
            'market_capitalisation': '4',
            'trading_volume': '5'
        }

        crypt_currency = dict()

        for key, value in opts.iteritems():
            info = tree.xpath('//div[@class="col-xs-12"]/div/table[@class="table"]/tbody/tr/td[' + value + ']/text()')[0]
            if value in('3', '4', '5'):
                crypt_currency[key] = self.clean_currency_amount(info)
            else:
                crypt_currency[key] = info

        # append actual timestamp
        crypt_currency['date'] = int(time.time())

        # append the exchange_rate
        crypt_currency['exchange_rate'] = exchange_rate.upper()

        return crypt_currency
```

**schema/DataSchema.py**

```
# coding: utf-8

from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from marshmallow import Schema, fields


class DataSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.String(required=True)
    tags = fields.List(fields.String(), required=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Awesome job overall, it is a breeze to review a structured code like this.

Here are some of notes I've come up with:

- [`optparse` was deprecated long time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217673/why-use-argparse-rather-than-optparse), you should switch to `argparse`
- `clean_currency_amount()` is actually a *static method* and should not be under the `CryptoScraper` class - probably it should be under the "utils" module
- I don't particularly like the way you've implemented `_get_currency_details()` - the way you define if a cell is of an "amount" type - I would do something more explicit, e.g.:

  ```
  headers = [
      ('currency', 'string'),
      ('code', 'string'),
      ('exchange_rate', 'amount'),
      ('market_capitalisation', 'amount'),
      ('trading_volume', 'amount')
  ]

  table = tree.xpath("//th[. = 'Kurs']/ancestor::table")[0]
  values = [cell.text for cell in table.findall(".//td")]

  crypt_currency = {}
  for (header, header_type), value in zip(headers, values):
      crypt_currency[header] = clean_currency_amount(value) if header_type == 'amount' else value
  ```

  Note, also, how I locate the desired `table` - I'm basically using a header name to find the "exchange" table - it is a bit better than what you current have because you are using the layout-oriented bootstrap class and have multiple parent nodes checked on the way to the desired element making the expression more fragile and less resistant to a change.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot for your review an helpful hints. I will apply your suggestions on my code. THANKS :)